# Retrieve Facebook page wall in android app

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-android-sdk

I want to get the wall posts on a Facebook page on my Android app and present it (It would be better to present it in the layout similar to official Facebook app for Android).

I have just started using Facebook SDK and am able to log in/out of my profile. I read various stackoverflow posts on this topic but I couldn't get things working with any of them. All I understood is that Graph API can be used to get Facebook page's contents. However, to access Facebook pages, it needs some authorization tokens, which I couldn't really understand. There being no simple actual tutorial on how to do this, it seems complicated to me.

Can anyone please simplify the steps to get the posts from Facebook page and present it in my app? Also, is it possible to get official Facebook App style layout for the presentation of page wall contents inside my app?

Any help would be appreciated.. thanks a lot in advance.. :)

Comment: You can follow the example of Hackbook which comes with Facebook sdk...

Comment: the Hackbook project doesnt say anything about getting a page feed.. :(